# Previous button doesn't work for “youtube-ios-player-helper”

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I have a problem with "youtube-ios-player-helper" for iOS (XCode / ObjC), i.e. previous button doesn't work. Next song in playlist works, but previous song doesn't work. It works with custom buttons for next and previous, like in [sample](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper), but embedded controls for previous song in playlist doesn't work. Does someone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/JV17/YoutubePlayer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already seen this sample. This sample is based on custom button outside the YTPlayerView. If I add a button and call function (on button click) 
[self.playerView previous];
it works. But I don't need a button outside the player. I need a button inside the player to work, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide minimal, complete and verifiable code. for the meantime, you may check the documentation of YouTube Helper Library here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper